# SQL Statement on creating a table with a composite key

Tags: sql, integer, many-to-many, composite-key

I am currently trying to create a simple relational database with Derby in java and am trying to code a table, tLinks, which will allow for a many to many relationship between 2 tables, tKW, and tFiles. I tried running the statement below but the syntax seems to be off. Any help would be welcomed.

```
"create table tLinks("
        + " linkKwId integer, linkFileId integer"
        + " constraint linksprimary_key primary key (linkKwId,linkFileId))";
```

Comment: Does it actually fail? What is the error?

Comment: Do you need a comma after "linkFileID integer" and the "constraint" keyword?

Comment: I do in fact need a comma, thank-you for your help